# Draw Unity Texture2D through Android plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, texture2d

I've created simple Android plugin which should draw Unity Texture2D through simple OpenGL commands.

Here's my Unity code:

```
private void InitAndroidStreamerObject()
    {
        androidStreamerObj = new AndroidJavaObject("makeitbetter.figazzz.com.vitamiousing7.AndroidStreamer");
        _testTex = new Texture2D(50, 50, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        System.IntPtr testPTR = _testTex.GetNativeTexturePtr();
        androidStreamerObj.Call("UpdateTestTexture", testPTR.ToInt32());
        _testTex.Apply();

        Debug.Log("Updated");
    }
```

And here's my Android plugin:

```
public void UpdateTestTexture(int nTexId)
    {
        Log.d("Unity", "hop hop hop");
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, nTexId);
        checkGlError("glBindTexture");

        int[] buf = new int[50 * 50];
        textureBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buf.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        byte[] colors = new byte[] {(byte) 255, (byte) 10, (byte) 10, (byte) 200};
        textureBuffer.put(colors);

        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, 50, 50, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
        checkGlError("glTexImage2D");
        //GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, 50, 50, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        checkGlError("glClearColor");
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        checkGlError("glClear");

    }
```

I've been struggling with it for 2 days, but the texture is still doesn't change. I'm checking all opengl operations, they seems to be fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Impressive - even if it doesn't work yet it's impressive!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it sarcasm? :)

Comment: Not really, I don't believe in sarcasm! You have some minor bug, but it is outstanding code.  Cheers...

Comment: I've done couple of fixes and it seems like I made it work. I'll give the answer to my question tomorrow.

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev do you have solution for it ?  Thanks

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev any news? I do have some similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554697/only-getting-one-pixel-from-an-external-texture

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you fix it?

Comment: I wrote low level native render plugin which is a bridge between Android and Unity spaces

Comment: Can you please tell what you wrote and how you solve it ?

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev Saying that you solved it without providing a solution is not helpful to others with a similar problem. You expect other people to answer your question but then don't provide an answer when you find one?

Comment: @palebone low level native render plugin is a big and complex solution built from small ones. If answer to that question was simple, of course I would share it, why wouldn't I? But in this particular case stackoverflow is not the platform for sharing a solution.

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev If you can't provide the entire solution, at least give people some pointers as to what to look at and/or how to approach a solution.